# Using curl flags in angular $http request

Tags: angularjs, http, curl, paypal

I have the following curl to send a request to PayPal and get the token back:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept-Language: en_US" -u "username:secret" -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

I need this request sent from angular $http, but I don't know how to "translate" it properly.

I know -H stands for Header and -d stands for data, but I don't know how to pass the (-u )user flag via http request.

Comment: that would be crazy. You would be exposing your credentials in the browser. Some requests must always be made from a server

Comment: I did not realize that. Thanks for the heads up. Anyway, I got it working by sending via Basic Authentication header.